# Detection if input sentence represents an incomplete sentence?

Tags: computational-linguistics, nltk

I am curious if there is an automated way to detect if a given string, representing a sentence, is an 'incomplete' sentence. By this I mean that either the text is not grammatically correct, or is missing words, or doesn't make much sense.

Previous research shows how to fill in missing tokens into a text that is incomplete, which is interesting, but I am looking to just detect if what is given as input is a complete sentence or not.

I am sure that there are many edge cases with something like this, but I am just looking for either state of the art implementations or ideas on how to do this manually, with nltk, opennlp or the stanford tools. Thanks in advance for any thoughts or advice!

Comment: Uh, you say it is known how to fill in missing tokens to make an incomplete sentence complete, so if you want to tell whether a sentence is complete, why don't you just check to see if any tokens must be added to make it complete?  If so, it was incomplete.

Comment: Parse the sentence with any rule-based parser. If it fails, the sentence is ill-formed (with respect to the used grammar). The sentence is incomplete (that is, missing "something") if an obligatory valency slot is empty.

Comment: @GregLee Thanks for the suggestion. What I was referring to was something like the answer on this question: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6519/filling-in-incomplete-sentences-using-nlp-and-python. Initially, it seemed like you needed to know where the missing tokens would be; I figured even a correct sentence could potentially have words added and keep it correct. Anyway, I should spend sometime reading the paper referenced.

Comment: @Atamiri: Do you have any recommendations for rule-based parsers that work well in our experience?

Comment: It depends on what you want to parse. LFG is a good choice in most cases.

Comment: Interesting. I will look into that. The text I am working on are short sentences that express an 'assertion'. I'll check out LFG. Would you happen to know of any good research?

Comment: Actually the technique suggested in the answer to
http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6519 does not require
you to know in advance where are the missing token. There is a variant
that can take missing tokens, or remove extra token (either or both),
or do some other corrections anywhere. Then you can get different
parses with a weight proportional to the number and type of
modification. If the sentence is parsable without changes, thoses
parses have weight zero. So that should answer all your demands.

Comment: Research on what? Writing a grammar? "A grammar writer's cookbook" is a good start.

Comment: @Atamiri It seems that the OP want to check whether the sentence is well formed, and also correct it (e.g. by adding missing tokens) if it is not.

Comment: @babou Yes, and my comment addressed this.

Comment: @Atamiri In what way does your comment address correcting an ill formed sentence?

Comment: I was just looking to detect if its complete or incomplete, but knowing what to suggest as a correction might be useful. The requirement for me right now is just detection.

@atamiri: Thanks for the suggestion for "A grammar writer's cookbook". I'll definitely make sure to look at it at some point.

Comment: @mrquintopolous You are welcome. Suggesting a correction will depend on how "broken" the sentence is. If it's incomplete that the empty slot in a valency frame will tell you what's missing and you could tell the user that, for example, an indirect object is missing, or a VP complement. Could you give an example of an incomplete sentence and what the corrected version should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to have an editing automaton, which is actually a
GSM (Generalized sequentil machine) that can do modifications on the
string. Each modification can have an associated cost. You can include
it in the parsing process, using a chart parser, to get parses up to
some modification, each with a weight accounting for the number and
types of modification. This will slow down the parser, but it does not
change its complexity, because the editing GSM is a finite state
machine, an thus does not change the language class.

When you get a parse with weight 0, it means that the input string
could be parsed without any editing.

This is very briefly addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903007/algorithms-or-data-structures-for-dealing-with-ambiguity/26132215#26132215) on another SE site.

Comment: See also [this
answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33514#33541) to the
question *Natural Language Parser that can handle syntactic and
lexical errors* and [this other
answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33145#33185) to the
question *Computing the closest match of an automaton and a string*.
You can also search for "*levenshtein distance*".

Comment: Thank you for all the lists. I will review all the links you sent me, but it sounds like a good approach. Do you have any suggestions for a GSM that I can use to play with some examples?

Comment: @mrquintopolous I have no idea what is ready-made on the web, if any.  A good way to
start is to use a simple GSM that modifies its input token string by
inserting an arbitrary token anywhere, non-deterministically, between
any two tokens of the input string. Whenever a token is inserted, you
increase the weight of the corresponding parses by one. To keep the
parsing cost down, you can ignore any parse that starts exceeding a
given weight (i.e. a given number of corrections). This will work only
for missing tokens.  But the same technique can deal with many other
types of ill-formedness.

Comment: I will be working on this in the next few weeks, so hopefully I will be able to try out everyone's suggestions then. For now, I'll give you the answer :)